# What's the functional way or one liner to do "a = b; a.foreach(...); a"?

Tags: scala

Is there a one-liner (or functional way) to do this?

```
val a = b
a.foreach(_.sideEffectFunc())
return a
```

Comment: You'll have to give more detail.  Is _sideEffectFunc supposed to modify the internals of `a` (or `b`, I guess)?  Presumably you already have a `b` from further up in your code, so I'm wondering why you're assigning it to a temp variable just to return it like that?  Assuming sideEffectFunc doesn't modify anything, `b.map(x => {x.sideEffectFunc(); x})` would work...  Though it'd be ugly.

Comment: Is `sideEffectFunc()` accumulating data into `a`, or something? I can't imagine any reason why you'd want to call it in a loop, and then return a, unless what it's doing is accumulating some value into a. In which case, you'd probably want to write a _non-side-effecting_ version of the function and use `.foldLeft` (or `.reduceLeft`) to get the results you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b.map(x => { x.sideEffectFunc(); x })
```

Comment: `b map { x => x.sideEffect(); x }` is a little easier on the eyes.